# Computing LBP Histogram using OpenCV in android

Tags: android, opencv, lbph-algorithm

I am doing face recognition in android using OpenCV SDK for android. I used the sample code of face detection that comes with OpenCV android SDK. Now I want to move to face recognition. I want to compute the LBP Histogram of the detected face and store it in the database which will be later matched using Chi-square with other histogram. The Face recognizer class in OpenCV has train and predict method which are not publicly exposed. Does the train method compute the Histogram of the image? How can I compute the LBP Histogram using the face recognizer class?

Comment: Hi @Uroosa did you make it working? or any progress?